# Why `inf` represent float overflow?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

This program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    float var_f = 9.999e38; //overflow the float
    std::cout << var_f;

    std::cin.get();
    return  0;  
}
```

prints out: `inf`

1. Does `inf` here represent infinity (∞) ?
2. **Why**, when `9.999e38` is not infinity (which can be store by double type) ?
3. Why it only happen with `float`, when:

   `unsigned long int var_i = 4294967296; //overflow integer`

   give me `0`(like we always know) if I print `var_i` out.

I used Visual Studio 2015 for this.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_types.htm - your number is too big!

Comment: To Infinity and beyond!

Comment: @EdHeal , no it's not big, it can be stored  by double, I used it to overflow a float

Comment: double has way more bits to throw at storage.

Comment: Are you thinking that a float should wrap back around to zero on overflow?

Comment: @VaughnCato, No, I just think it would be a number instead of represent by `inf`

Comment: What number would it be if it was too large to hold in a float?

Comment: @VaughnCato you can see that's I confuse with integer case. At first, I thought it would be a garbage number, but now I get the point,If we will assign a value which is beyond the maximum value of float data type compiler will assign +INF if number is positive and –INF if number is negative, no matter the value is in range of double of or not.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Does inf here represent infinity (∞) ?

Yes. See [std::numeric_limits::infinity](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/infinity).

> 2. Why, when 9.999e38 is not infinity (which can be store by double type) ?

It's infinity for `float` (not for `double`). It's greater than the largest representable number of `float` (i.e. `3.402823466e+38`, or `0X7F7FFFFF`).

> 3. Why it only happen with float

Because it's meaningful for floating-point number, but not for an integer number. According to the IEEE754 (Floating-Point Representation), the positive infinity is the value with all bits of the exponent set and all bits of the fraction cleared (i.e. `0x7f800000`), which is greater than the largest finite value of `float` (i.e. `0X7F7FFFFF`).

[Floating point number representation](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/floating_point/understanding_floating_point_representation.html)
[IEEE Floating-Point Representation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b34tf65.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `inf` is a special value indicating that the value is too large to be stored in that object.  In your case, you are trying to convert a `double` value to a `float`.  Since the value is too large to be stored in a `float`, it stores `inf` instead.

Floating point types (`float`, `double`, `long double`) work this way, but integral types do not have an `inf` value.